# How to stay on same app when closing window

Tags: 16.04, application-switcher, focus

Say I have Firefox and several Document Viewer windows open. When I switch apps to Document Viewer and close the current window I expect the next Document Viewer window to get focus. What instead happens is that I am switched to Firefox.

How do I get the behaviour I want?

Comment: And what is a "document viewer"?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen that's the name of the other app. Substitute any other app and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen My guess is that "Document Viewer" is Evince like "Text Editor" is Gedit.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's important what Document Viewer is. All apps work the same way.

Comment: I see the same thing in Kubuntu 18.04. In this specific case, does Document Viewer have tabs? If you use tabs instead of separate windows, you can get around the problem by just closing the tab. I know it's not the answer you want!

Comment: @DKBose you're right it's Evince. It doesn't have tabs from what I can see.

Comment: This would be such a convenient feature for all the mac folks wanting to switch to Linux. Keeping context is one thing that mac is really good at, and once used to that, you really wish there would be an easy way to have that in Linux too.